# BlueZone screens called by VBA

Tags: excel, vba, emulation

I use several screens in BlueZone that have 5 alpha character calls "ABCDE", "BCDEF", etc. Users have to (1) hit F3 (2) Enter (3) type alpha characters (4) enter.

I want a simple navigation pane via VBA that displays all the screens I want as buttons - click and call. E.g. I click a button labeled "ABCDE" and that screen comes up.

I do not have access to BlueZone's VBA add-on. I am able to record/write the macros in the program as .bss files, though. There is no way to add nice buttons in BlueZone, on purpose I assume, to call the macros, though.

To use the macros in BlueZone, you have to select a drop down and then your macro...

I know I can open all kinds of files in VBA with Shell(), but can I manipulate an emulator like BlueZone to run the macros via VBA?

Answer (score 0):

```
    Sub ARDAA()

Set bzhao = CreateObject("BZWhll.WhllObj")
  bzhao.Connect ""

bzhao.SendKey "<PF3>"
bzhao.WaitForString "[0;7mA" & Chr(27) & "[0m", 30
bzhao.SendKey "a"
bzhao.WaitForString "[0;7mA" & Chr(27) & "[0m", 30
bzhao.SendKey "r"
bzhao.WaitForString "[0;7mA" & Chr(27) & "[0m", 30
bzhao.SendKey "d"
bzhao.WaitForString "[0;7mA" & Chr(27) & "[0m", 30
bzhao.SendKey "a"
bzhao.WaitForString "[0;7mA" & Chr(27) & "[0m", 30
bzhao.SendKey "a"
bzhao.WaitForString "[0;7mA" & Chr(27) & "[0m", 30
bzhao.SendKey "<Enter>"

End Sub
```

I was unable to find a call to navigate to a screen, so here is VBA simply calling the key strokes.

Answer (score 0):

You can make make a navigation pane of-sorts using [BlueZone's power pads](https://www3.rocketsoftware.com/bluezone/help/v42/en/bz/POWER_PADS/Power_Pads_Overview.htm)

You can associate each of the buttons with a macro, script, or other "actions."

You can also coordinate all sorts of emulation with VBA, but some of it will take some trial on your end and watching how your mainframe behaves.  I'd suggest code similar to the following, but this is based on how our mainframe works...

```
' writes "ABCDE" at the given screen row and column
Sub ABCDE(row, column)
    Set host = CreateObject("BZWhll.WhllObj")
    host.Connect ""

    host.SendKey "<PF3>"
    host.WaitReady 10, 1

    host.SendKey "<Enter>"
    host.WaitReady 10, 1

    host.WriteScreen "ABCDE", row, column
End Sub
```